# Printing full symbolic link information, starting from a root directory

Tags: linux, symlink

We are interested in printing all the symbolic link information, starting from a root directory.  We would like the information to be printed in the following format:
`symbolic name -> actual name`       *[Notice the same line]*

We have tried the following and it gives us the symbolic name and actual name, **but on different lines**:
`find . -type l -print -exec readlink -f {} \;`

Comment: hm, what if I do `ln -s /dev/null 'heaven -> back'`, or make a symlink with a line break in its name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you were far off. Use `-printf` instead of `-print` (assuming your version of `find` has it) and you get this

```
find / -type l -printf "%p -> " -exec readlink -f {} \;
```

Example output

```
/bin/apropos -> /bin/whatis
/bin/awk -> /bin/gawk
/bin/bzcmp -> /bin/bzdiff
```

For reference,

```
ls -gl /bin/apropos
lrwxrwxrwx 1 roaima 10 Mar 28 20:15 /bin/apropos -> whatis
```

You will get overstruck lines for broken links (`-printf` without a newline)

Comment: AFAIK `-printf` is specific to the GNU implementation of `find`. With any implementation, you can always do `-exec printf '%s -> ' {} \;`.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
for link (**/*(ND@^-@)) print -r -- "$link -> $link:P"
```

Where `@^-@` restricts the glob expansion to non-broken symlink files (symlinks for which the target is accessible, a necessary condition for its canonical path to be determined, the equivalent of GNU `find`'s `-type l ! -xtype l`). `$link:P` gives the realpath of the link (the canonical absolute path after symlinks resolution of all components similar to what the `realpath()` standard function does, or GNU `readlink -f`).